# Generic data constructor for Data instance

Tags: haskell, scrap-your-boilerplate

Given a datatype

```
data Foo = IFoo Int | SFoo String deriving (Data, Typeable)
```

what is a simple definition of

```
gconstr :: (Typeable a, Data t) => a -> t
```

such that

```
gconstr (5 :: Int) :: Foo == IFoo 5
gconstr "asdf" :: Foo == SFoo "asdf"
gconstr True :: Foo == _|_
```

It would be essentially the opposite of syb's `gfindtype`.

Or does such a thing exist already? I've tried hoogle-ing the type and haven't found much, but the syb types are kind of hard to interpret. A function returning `Nothing` on error is also acceptable.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect that `Data.Dynamic` would be better for my needs, but I'm still curious about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be possible, though it's not completely trivial.

Preliminaries:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Control.Monad ( msum )
import Data.Data
import Data.Maybe
```

First a helper function `gconstrn`, which tries to do the same thing as required of `gconstr`, but for a specific constructor only:

```
gconstrn :: (Typeable a, Data t) => Constr -> a -> Maybe t
gconstrn constr arg = gunfold addArg Just constr
    where
        addArg :: Data b => Maybe (b -> r) -> Maybe r
        addArg Nothing = Nothing
        addArg (Just f) =
            case cast arg of
                Just v -> Just (f v)
                Nothing -> Nothing
```

The key part is that the `addArg` function will use `arg` as an argument to the constructor, *if* the types match.

Essentially `gunfold` starts unfolding with `Just IFoo` or `Just SFoo`, and then the next step is to try `addArg` to provide it with its argument.

For multi-argument constructors this would be called repeatedly, so if you defined an `IIFoo` constructor that took two `Int`s, it would also get successfully filled in by `gconstrn`. Obviously with a bit more work you could do something more sophisticated like providing a list of arguments.

Then it's just a question of trying this with all possible constructors. The recursive definition between `result` and `dt` is just to get the right type argument for `dataTypeOf`, the actual value being passed in doesn't matter at all. `ScopedTypeVariables` would be an alternative for achieving this.

```
gconstr :: (Typeable a, Data t) => a -> Maybe t
gconstr arg = result
    where result = msum [gconstrn constr arg | constr <- dataTypeConstrs dt]
          dt = dataTypeOf (fromJust result)
```

As discussed in the comments, both functions can be simplified with `<*>` from `Control.Applicative` to the following, though it's a bit harder to see what's going on in the `gunfold`:

```
gconstr :: (Typeable a, Data t) => a -> Maybe t
gconstr arg = result
    where
        result = msum $ map (gunfold (<*> cast arg) Just) (dataTypeConstrs dt)
        dt = dataTypeOf (fromJust result)
```

Comment: That appears to work. Also, the `Maybe` monad formulation of `addArg` isn't too bad, it's something like `addArg a = do {f <- a; v <- cast arg; return (f v)}`

Comment: Actually, an `Applicative` form would be simpler, just `addArg a = a <*> cast arg`

Comment: Yes, it looks nice, but I think it would have confused me if I'd been reading it that way to begin with. The `Applicative` is more appealing though.

Comment: The `Applicative` also means you can partially apply directly in the `gunfold` call, which in turn makes it reasonable to inline `gconstrn` into `gconstr` - the list comprehension result just becomes `gunfold (<*> cast arg) Just (indexConstr dt n)`. I think that probably swings it.

Comment: Just noticed `dataTypeConstrs` which simplifies things further